# How do I vertically align an inline image?

Tags: support, images

I just used this image [image] in a question, and I think you'll agree that it would look much better if the image was lowered a bit. I tried the html code

```
<img src="http://mathurl.com/332t642.png" style="vertical-align:-5px">
```

but this didn't work: The image just didn't show up. (The 5 pixel adjustment I obtained by testing in a separate html file.) Is there another way to vertically align the image?

Comment: Just put it on a separate line? We don't need to save space here that much.

Comment: I did consider that, yes, but for such a small image I found an extra line a bit strange. With the vertical align of `-5px` it did look rather nice inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list of what HTML tags and attributes are allowed on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).  The allowed attributes on images form a rather small set; I don't know if playing with the height or width would help, but that's all you've got, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the list of allowed attributes and other stuff. That makes it clear why my attempt didn't work. Playing with height and width doesn't help either, so I'll probably have to live with the ugly rendering.